# How to test patch method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

How to properly test entity update methods? I am unable to do this correctly.

First, in the test, I generate my product, then I call the `patch()` method and pass an array with new data as the second argument.

But when I look at what is in the database with `dd(Product::all())` at the end of the test, I see that the generated product data is there, and not the data that I added when changing the product.

And the test passes well, without errors, although the data is not what I expect

```
public function test_check_count_additional_photos()
{
    $product = Product::factory()->create();

    $this->actingAs($this->user)->patch(route('editProduct', ['id' => $this->user->id, 'product' => $product->id]), [
        'title' => 'Updated product',
        'description' => 'Updated Product description',
        'price' => 1000,
        'visible' => true,
    ]);

    dd(Product::all())
}
```

And controller

```
public function editProduct(int $userId, Product $product, UpdateProductRequest $request)
{
    $product->title = isset($request->title) ? $request->title :  $product->title;
    $product->description = isset($request->description) ? $request->description : $product->description;
    $product->price = isset($request->price)  ? $request->price : $product->price;
    $product->visible = isset($request->visible) ? 1 : 0;
    $product->user_id = $userId;
    $product->update();
}
```

Comment: Can you use `save()` method instead of update see it fix it or not.

Comment: The save() method during testing creates another record in the database, rather than updating the desired one

Answer (score 1):

After setting updated properties, you need to use the `save()` method in the controller, not the `update()` method.

If your properties are unguarded, you can use `update()` by providing an array, like this:

```
$product->update([
    'title' => isset($request->title) ? $request->title :  $product->title,
    'description' => isset($request->description) ? $request->description : $product->description,
    'price' => isset($request->price) ? $request->price : $product->price,
    'visible' => isset($request->visible) ? 1 : 0,
    'user_id' => $userId,
]);
```

Comment: The save() method, when updated, creates another record in the database, and does not update it